# jsTree: Getting a node by Id and creating a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I've found in several places on the web the jsTree create/get_node functions but cannot make this work. When a user clicks on a button, I need to get the parent node using its Id and create a child (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/G789k/339/)). What's wrong with this code?

This is the HTML:

```
<form>
<input value="Create Child" type="button" onclick="createChild();" />
</form>

<div id="treediv" />
```

And this is the javascript:

```
        var sqltree = [
             { "data" : "Node1", "metadata": { "id" : "id1" } , "attr":{"rel":"rel1"} },
             { "data" : "Node2", "metadata": { "id" : "id2" }, "attr":{"rel":"rel2"} },
             { "data" : "Node3", "metadata": { "id" : "id3" }, "attr":{"rel":"rel3"} }
         ];


        $("#treediv").jstree({
            "json_data" : { "data" : sqltree },
            "plugins" : [ "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "types" ]
        });




      function createChild(){
             alert ('createChild invoked');
             var newNode = { data: "Child1" };
             var parentNode = $('#treediv').get_node("[id='id2']"); 
             $("#treediv").jstree("create",parentNode,"first",newNode,false,true);
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change :

```
var parentNode = $('#treediv').get_node("[id='id2']");
```

To:

```
var parentNode = $('#treediv').find("[id='id2']");
```

Comment: juvian, your solution doesn't work, look at  http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/G789k/341/

Comment: @user1362485 A new child does appear, what are you trying to do?

Comment: The parent node should be Node2 (Id=Id2). Thanks.

Comment: @user1362485 doesnt seem possible unless you want to add a node to selected or clicked node

Comment: thanks juvian, selecting the node before creating the child works. Not sure why the node needs to be selected, though. This is the final [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G789k/342)

Comment: You do not have to select the node first. The problem was in your JSON. You had the `id` in `metadata`, there jsTree couldn't find it. Look at this jsFiddle for clarification. http://jsfiddle.net/gXu6X/4/

Answer (score 7):

If you reference the jsTree instance:

```
treeInst = $('#treediv').jstree()      # create new instance 
treeInst = $('#treediv').jstree(true)  # get existing instance
```

Then you can get a node by it's id:

```
node = treeInst.get_node( node_id )
```